# Aplicativo para vários perfis de usuários

Tags: android

Em serviços de transporte eu vejo dois aplicativos o app do prestador e do usuário.

Tive uma solicitação de um desenvolvimento e no escopo do projeto foi identificado  vários perfis, no Android eu não encontrei nem nunca fiz algo deste tipo diferente de soluções web ou desktop´s que gerenciam o menu ou funções do sistema e habilitam/desabilitam recursos dependendo do perfil do usuário logado.

Imaginei criar dois aplicativos um para usuário e outro corporativo mais o meu solicitante ainda insistiu em um único app, algum dos senhores que tenham passado por projeto com funções de perfis poderia comentar sobre isto? como relatei não cheguei a fazer nada com este tipo de recurso em dispositivo móveis nativo.

Comment: Faça um aplicativo modulado (dividido em bibliotecas: usuario, corporativo). Talvez seja essa uma das soluções.

Comment: a base do app vai ser a tela de login... A partir dela, você redireciona para, por exemplo, MainActivityUsuario ou MainActivityPrestador.

Comment: Você poderia ter duas Activity como disse o @Mr_Anderson se as diferenças forem grandes. Se forem pequenas você poderia ter apenas uma Activity e então exibiria ou não alguns recursos em função do login

Comment: se fosse desenvolver isso, faria um site na web e abriria esse site num webview nativo para aproveitar todas as funcionalidades que o java oferece para manipulação desse tipo de dados, dessa forma basta voce criar um site responsivo e voilá, abre ele na tela do aparelho, quem logar vai ser direcionado igualmente ao se logar num site pelo desktop.

Comment: Olá a todos, obrigado pelos comentários, acredito que a sugestão do Sr. @Mr_Anderson seja a mais acertada, vou implementar esta abordagem.